# Any OSTN02 libraries for Windows CE

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, sdk, gps

I'm looking for either some C or C++ source library, or DLL or static libraries that will include Windows CE/Mobile verions, to convert between WGS84 geodetic coordinates and the OSTN02 grid and OSGM02 datum.  For the Win32 platforms I already use the [Quest](http://www.qgsl.com/?product=gridinquest) libraries, but they have nothing for CE based platforms.  I have looked at the [Blue marble libraries](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/), but they appear to costly to deploy.  I don't mind paying a reasonable price for an SDK, but not one that requires a per license run-time royalty.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you are still looking, but Eye4Software ( [http://www.eye4software.com )](http://www.eye4software.com) offers such a component.
The OSTN02 functionality is sold seperately,

Leon